# Rotate a 2D curve into 3D one

Tags: tikz-pgf, pgfplots

I 've used Tikz to generate this 2D plot. I want to get its 3D version by rotating it throw the axis z.
Is there any Tikz special command that can do that ?
Thank you

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\begin{document}
\begin{center}
\begin{tikzpicture}[scale=6]
\draw[-] (0,2,0)--(-0.5,1,0).. controls (-1,0,0) and (1,0,0).. 
   (0.5,1,0)--(0,2,0);
 \draw[dashed](0,-0.1,0)--(0,2.1,0);
 \node [above] at (0,2.1,0) {$\boldsymbol{Z}$};
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{center}    
 \end{document}
```

Comment: Asymptote is a more appropriate package for 3d modelling, at the moment.

Answer (score 5):

Yes, there is. `tikz-3dplot` with the `3d` library that it auto-loads. The rotation angle is the second argument of `\tdplotsetmaincoords{90}{70}` in the following MWE:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage{tikz-3dplot}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\begin{document}
\begin{center}
\tdplotsetmaincoords{90}{70} 
\begin{tikzpicture}[tdplot_main_coords,scale=6,canvas is xz plane at y=0]
\draw[-] (0,2)--(-0.5,1).. controls (-1,0) and (1,0).. 
   (0.5,1)--(0,2);
 \draw[dashed](0,-0.1)--(0,2.1);
 \node [above] at (0,2.1) {$\boldsymbol{Z}$};
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{center}    
\end{document}
```

[image]

An animation for illustration what the rotation angle means.

```
\documentclass[tikz,border=3mm]{standalone}
\usepackage{tikz-3dplot}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\begin{document}
\foreach \X in {5,15,...,355}
{\tdplotsetmaincoords{90}{\X} 
\begin{tikzpicture}[tdplot_main_coords,scale=6]
\path[use as bounding box,tdplot_screen_coords] (-1,-0.5) rectangle (1,2.5);
\begin{scope}[canvas is xz plane at y=0]
\draw[-] (0,2)--(-0.5,1).. controls (-1,0) and (1,0).. 
   (0.5,1)--(0,2);
 \draw[dashed](0,-0.1)--(0,2.1);
 \node [above] at (0,2.1) {$\boldsymbol{Z}$};
\end{scope} 
\end{tikzpicture}}
\end{document}
```

[image]

This can be used to fill a surface.

```
\documentclass[tikz,border=3mm]{standalone}
\usepackage{tikz-3dplot}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\begin{document}

\begin{tikzpicture}[scale=6]
\tdplotsetmaincoords{90}{0} 
 \path[use as bounding box,tdplot_screen_coords] (-1,-0.5) rectangle (1,2.5);
 \foreach \X [count=\Y] in {0,1,...,89}
 {\tdplotsetrotatedcoords{00}{0}{\X}
 \pgfmathtruncatemacro{\ccol}{100-0.7*\Y} 
 \begin{scope}[tdplot_rotated_coords,canvas is xz plane at y=0]
  \path[fill=blue!\ccol] (0,2)--(-0.5,1).. controls (-1,0) and (1,0).. 
    (0.5,1)--(0,2);
 \end{scope} }
 \draw[dashed](0,-0.1)--(0,2.1);
 \node [above] at (0,2.1) {$\boldsymbol{Z}$};
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]

**ADDENDUM**: As for the clarified question: AFAIK there is not a simple switch that provides you with the surface. However, if you have a function that approximates the Bezier curve, you can use `pgfplots` to draw the rotational surface.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\pgfplotsset{compat=1.16}

\usepackage{amsmath}
\begin{document}
\begin{center}
\begin{tikzpicture}
\begin{axis}[unit vector ratio=1 1 1,scale=6,hide axis,colormap/viridis]
\addplot3[surf,shader=interp,z buffer=sort,domain y=0:180,domain=0:360]
({2*sin(x)*sin(y)/3},{2*cos(x)*sin(y)/3},{0.5*(1+ifthenelse(abs(y)<90,(90-abs(y))*6/180,0.7*cos(y)))});  
\end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{center}    
\end{document}
```

[image]

Yet I agree [with Benjamin McKay that asymptote is a more appropriate tool for that](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/512230/rotate-a-2d-curve-into-3d-one/512233#comment1295368_512230).

Comment: this is not a 3D plot ! my question is about getting a 3d surface from may 2d one

Comment: @rihani Sorry, misunderstanding, but your question does not mention "surface".

Comment: Nice answer marmot. Erm, old marmot. Erm, Schrödinger's cat!